# What is the difference between a data lakehouse and a delta lake?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, data-lakehouse

I am new to Databricks. I am reading Microsoft documentation on data lakehouse. In the documentation they make reference to delta lake without explaining what the difference is or even if there is any. Can someone please help explain this to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lakehouse is a paradigm coined by this [paper](https://www.cidrdb.org/cidr2021/papers/cidr2021_paper17.pdf), while Delta Lake is a technology that can be used to create a Lakehouse-like Data platform.

Alternatives to the Lakehouse are:

- Basic Data Lakes
- Data Warehouses

Alternatives to Delta Lake are:

- Apache Iceberg
- Apache Hudi

I hope this makes it a little bit more clear.

Comment: Okay I think I get it. So data lakehouse is the concept and delta lake is the technology used by Databricks similar to how data lake is the concept and Azure Data Lake is the technology used by Azure or Data warehouse is the concept and Amazon redshift is the technology used. Would this be a correct way of looking at it?.

Comment: This is exactly it! :)

Answer (score 0):

One picture is worth a thousand words. Delta Lake is a technology, while Lakehouse is a concept.
Delta Lake is an implementation that can be used to create a Lakehouse-like data platform.
Lakehouse is a broader concept that encompasses technologies like Delta Lake.[image]